# Duplicated objects not saving their new transformations after reopening blend file

Tags: objects

I am using blender 2.8, I made some windows for my house and when I copy paste them into holes and then save->reopen they all go back to position of original window, rotation and scale is reseted too.

Any solution for this?

Comment: Have you accidentally set keyframes for the objects?

Comment: Ops, that was it.
Never crossed my mind to check timeline, thanks for help.